# Expected height of special binary tree

Tags: permutations, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, trees

At any instant, every leaf node has an equal probability of splitting. So let's say initially at $t=0$ we have just 1 node. Then at $t=1$, we have 2 leaf nodes. At $t=2$ we have 3 leaf nodes with two possible tree structures. What will be the expected height of the tree at time $t=N$ with $N+1$ leaf nodes? (At any instant only one leaf node can branch into two children nodes). What will be a tight upper bound to the above expectation?

$E[H_{1}]=1$
$E[H_{2}]=2$
$E[H_{3}]=\frac{3+3+2+3+3+2}{6}=\frac{8}{3}$

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJKbW.jpg)

Comment: Some data . . .
$$
E[H_{1}]=1\\
E[H_{2}]=2\\
E[H_{3}]=\frac{8}{3}\approx 2.667\\
E[H_{4}]=\frac{10}{3}\approx 3.333\\
E[H_{5}]=\frac{19}{5}=3.8\\
E[H_{6}]=\frac{64}{15}\approx 4.267\\
E[H_{7}]=\frac{1471}{315}\approx 4.670\\
E[H_{8}]=\frac{3161}{630}\approx 5.017\\
E[H_{9}]=\frac{3028}{567}\approx 5.340\\
E[H_{10}]=\frac{6397}{1134}\approx 5.641
$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you share the code of the simulation if it was simulated?

Comment: Not a smulation. Exact values. Brute force program. For problems such as this, you should have some basic prograamming ability, so I'll leave that task to you.